# Name wont resolve on websites

Tags: ubuntu, dns, network-adapter

I have replaced the network card on my Ubuntu server and any site that I have using the name-server on that box is not resolving. I have other sites that are hosted on the same webserver but have a different dns server and they still work. I have renamed the new network card nics to eth0 and eth1 like they were before. The only thing I can think of is a setting that uses the mac address or some setting in the card that would stop bind from working. the card is a Intel EXPI9402PTBLK.

this is the output for my syslog I dont see anything wrong but could someone take a look at it

```
Jul 20 09:29:42 rtr-slc-001 named[15896]: starting BIND 9.7.0-P1 -u bind
Jul 20 09:29:42 rtr-slc-001 named[15896]: built with '--prefix=/usr' '--mandir=/usr/share/man' '--infodir=/usr/share/info' '--sysconfdir=/etc/bind' '--localstatedir=/  var' '--enable-threads' '--enable-largefile' '--with-libtool' '--enable-   shared' '--enable-static' '--with-openssl=/usr' '--with-gssapi=/usr' '--with-gnu-ld' '--     with-d  lz-postgres=no' '--with-dlz-mysql=no' '--with-dlz-bdb=yes' '--with-dlz-filesystem=yes' '--with-dlz-ldap=yes' '--with-dlz-stub=yes' '--with-geoip=/usr' '--enable-ipv6'   'CFLAGS=-fno-strict-aliasing -DDIG_SIGCHASE -O2' 'LDFLAGS=-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions' 'CPPFLAGS='
Jul 20 09:29:42 rtr-slc-001 named[15896]: adjusted limit on open files from 1024 to 1048576
Jul 20 09:29:42 rtr-slc-001 named[15896]: found 4 CPUs, using 4 worker threads
Jul 20 09:29:42 rtr-slc-001 named[15896]: using up to 4096 sockets
Jul 20 09:29:42 rtr-slc-001 named[15896]: loading configuration from '/etc/bind/named.conf'
Jul 20 09:29:42 rtr-slc-001 named[15896]: reading built-in trusted keys from file '/etc/bind/bind.keys'
Jul  20 09:29:42 rtr-slc-001 named[15896]: using default UDP/IPv4 port range: [1024, 65535]
Jul 20 09:29:42 rtr-slc-001 named[15896]: using default UDP/IPv6 port range: [1024, 65535]
Jul 20 09:29:42 rtr-slc-001 named[15896]: listening on IPv6 interfaces, port 53
Jul 20 09:29:42 rtr-slc-001 named[15896]: listening on IPv4 interface lo, 127.0.0.1#53
Jul 20 09:29:42 rtr-slc-001 named[15896]: listening on IPv4 interface eth0, public ip#53
Jul 20 09:29:42 rtr-slc-001 named[15896]: listening on IPv4 interface eth0:1,public ip#53
Jul 20 09:29:42 rtr-slc-001 named[15896]: listening on IPv4 interface eth0:2, public ip#53
Jul 20 09:29:42 rtr-slc-001 named[15896]: listening on IPv4 interface eth1, private ip#53
Jul 20 09:29:42 rtr-slc-001 named[15896]: listening on IPv4 interface as0t0, 10.8.0.1#53
Jul 20 09:29:42 rtr-slc-001 named[15896]: generating session key for dynamic DNS
Jul 20 09:29:42 rtr-slc-001 named[15896]: automatic empty zone: view internal: 254.169.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Jul 20 09:29:42 rtr-slc-001 named[15896]: automatic empty zone: view internal: 2.0.192.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Jul 20 09:29:42 rtr-slc-001 named[15896]: automatic empty zone: view internal: 255. 255.255.255.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Jul 20 09:29:42 rtr-slc-001 named[15896]: automatic empty zone: view internal: 0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.IP6.ARPA
 Jul 20 09:29:42 rtr-slc-001 named[15896]: automatic empty zone: view internal: 1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.IP6.ARPA
Jul 20 09:29:42 rtr-slc-001 named[15896]: automatic empty zone: view internal: D.F.IP6.ARPA
Jul 20 09:29:42 rtr-slc-001 named[15896]: automatic empty zone: view internal: 8.E.F.IP6.ARPA
Jul 20 09:29:42 rtr-slc-001 named[15896]: automatic empty zone: view internal: 9.E.F.IP6.ARPA
Jul 20 09:29:42 rtr-slc-001 named[15896]: automatic empty zone: view internal:   A.E.F.IP6.ARPA
Jul 20 09:29:42 rtr-slc-001 named[15896]: automatic empty zone: view internal: B.E.F.IP6.ARPA
Jul 20 09:29:42 rtr-slc-001 named[15896]: command channel listening on 127.0.0.1#953
Jul  20 09:29:42 rtr-slc-001 named[15896]: zone 0.in-addr.arpa/IN/internal: loaded serial 1
 Jul 20 09:29:42 rtr-slc-001 named[15896]: zone 127.in-addr.arpa/IN/internal: loaded serial 1
 Jul 20 09:29:42 rtr-slc-001 named[15896]: /var/lib/bind/db.192.168.8:3: ignoring out-of-zone data (.)
Jul 20 09:29:42 rtr-slc-001 named[15896]: /var/lib/bind/db.192.168.8:9: ignoring out-of-zone data (NS)
Jul 20 09:29:42 rtr-slc-001 named[15896]: /var/lib/bind/db.192.168.8:9: unknown RR type 'rtr-slc.001.trizonllc.com.'
Jul 20 09:29:42 rtr-slc-001 named[15896]: zone 8.168.192.in-addr.arpa/IN/internal: loading from master file /var/lib/bind/db.192.168.8 failed: unknown class/type
Jul 20 09:29:42 rtr-slc-001 named[15896]: zone 8.168.192.in-addr.arpa/IN/internal: not loaded due to errors.
Jul 20 09:29:42 rtr-slc-001 named[15896]: zone 255.in-addr.arpa/IN/internal: loaded serial 1
 Jul 20 09:29:42 rtr-slc-001 named[15896]: zone gotrizon.com/IN/internal: gotrizon.com/MX 'aspmx.l.google.com.gotrizon.com' has no address records (A or AAAA)
Jul 20 09:29:42 rtr-slc-001 named[15896]: zone gotrizon.com/IN/internal: loaded serial 1307247290
Jul 20 09:29:42 rtr-slc-001 named[15896]: /var/lib/bind/trizon.com.internal.hosts:15: ignoring out-of-zone data (calendar.gotrizon.com)
Jul 20 09:29:42 rtr-slc-001 named[15896]: /var/lib/bind/trizon.com.internal.hosts:16: ignoring out-of-zone data (docs.gotrizon.com)
Jul 20 09:29:42 rtr-slc-001 named[15896]: /var/lib/bind/trizon.com.internal.hosts:17: ignoring out-of-zone data (ftp.gotrizon.com)
Jul 20 09:29:42 rtr-slc-001 named[15896]: zone trizon.com/IN/internal: trizon.com/MX 'aspmx.l.google.com.trizon.com' has no address records (A or AAAA)
Jul 20 09:29:42 rtr-slc-001 named[15896]: zone trizon.com/IN/internal: loaded serial 1307247290
Jul 20 09:29:42 rtr-slc-001 named[15896]: zone trizonllc.com/IN/internal: loaded serial 1304718353
Jul 20 09:29:42 rtr-slc-001 named[15896]: zone localhost/IN/internal: loaded serial 2
Jul 20 09:29:42 rtr-slc-001 named[15896]: zone amerihomesgroup.com/IN/external: loaded serial 46
Jul 20 09:29:42 rtr-slc-001 named[15896]: zone cooleypro.com/IN/external: loaded serial 47
Jul 20 09:29:42 rtr-slc-001 named[15896]: zone czncorp.com/IN/external: loaded serial 1271769456
Jul 20 09:29:42 rtr-slc-001 named[15896]: zone doelevate.com/IN/external: loaded serial 29
Jul 20 09:29:42 rtr-slc-001 named[15896]: zone frontiersalessupport.com/IN/external: loaded serial 32
Jul 20 09:29:42 rtr-slc-001 named[15896]: zone getredrock.com/IN/external: loaded serial 49
Jul 20 09:29:42 rtr-slc-001 named[15896]: zone gotritech.com/IN/external: loaded serial 50
Jul 20 09:29:42 rtr-slc-001 named[15896]: zone gotrizon.com/IN/external: loaded serial 42
Jul 20 09:29:42 rtr-slc-001 named[15896]: zone maxguardid.com/IN/external: loaded serial 46
Jul 20 09:29:42 rtr-slc-001 named[15896]: zone redrk.com/IN/external: loaded serial 35
Jul 20 09:29:42 rtr-slc-001 named[15896]: zone redrocc.com/IN/external: loaded serial 36
Jul 20 09:29:42 rtr-slc-001 named[15896]: zone spectraseven.com/IN/external: loaded serial 46
Jul 20 09:29:42 rtr-slc-001 named[15896]: zone teltanium.com/IN/external: loaded serial 50
Jul 20 09:29:42 rtr-slc-001 named[15896]: zone transynergydirect.com/IN/external: loaded serial 13
Jul 20 09:29:42 rtr-slc-001 named[15896]: /var/lib/bind/trizon.com.hosts:19: ignoring out-of-zone data (/*trizon.com)
Jul 20 09:29:42 rtr-slc-001 named[15896]: zone trizon.com/IN/external: loaded serial 42
Jul 20 09:29:42 rtr-slc-001 named[15896]: zone trizonllc.com/IN/external: loaded serial 95
Jul 20 09:29:42 rtr-slc-001 named[15896]: zone trizonstall.com/IN/external: journal rollforward failed: journal out of sync with zone
Jul 20 09:29:42 rtr-slc-001 named[15896]: zone trizonstall.com/IN/external: not loaded due to errors.
Jul 20 09:29:42 rtr-slc-001 named[15896]: zone spectraseven.net/IN/external: loaded serial 1279921495
Jul 20 09:29:42 rtr-slc-001 named[15896]: zone trizonllc.net/IN/external: loaded serial 1279025138
Jul 20 09:29:42 rtr-slc-001 named[15896]: zone gotrizon.com/IN/internal: sending notifies (serial 1307247290)
Jul 20 09:29:42 rtr-slc-001 named[15896]: zone trizon.com/IN/internal: sending notifies (serial 1307247290)
Jul 20 09:29:42 rtr-slc-001 named[15896]: zone frontiersalessupport.com/IN/external: sending notifies (serial 32)
Jul 20 09:29:42 rtr-slc-001 named[15896]: zone spectraseven.net/IN/external: sending notifies (serial 1279921495)
Jul 20 09:29:42 rtr-slc-001 named[15896]: zone transynergydirect.com/IN/external: sending notifies (serial 13)
Jul 20 09:29:42 rtr-slc-001 named[15896]: zone redrocc.com/IN/external: sending notifies (serial 36)
Jul 20 09:29:42 rtr-slc-001 named[15896]: running
Jul 20 09:29:42 rtr-slc-001 named[15896]: zone redrk.com/IN/external: sending notifies (serial 35)
Jul 20 09:29:42 rtr-slc-001 named[15896]: zone maxguardid.com/IN/external: sending notifies (serial 46)
Jul 20 09:29:42 rtr-slc-001 named[15896]: zone trizonllc.com/IN/external: sending notifies (serial 95)
Jul 20 09:29:42 rtr-slc-001 named[15896]: zone gotrizon.com/IN/external: sending notifies (serial 42)
Jul 20 09:29:42 rtr-slc-001 named[15896]: zone spectraseven.com/IN/external: sending notifies (serial 46)
Jul   20 09:29:42 rtr-slc-001 named[15896]: zone doelevate.com/IN/external: sending notifies (serial 29)
Jul 20 09:29:42 rtr-slc-001 named[15896]: zone gotritech.com/IN/external: sending notifies (serial 50)
Jul 20 09:29:42 rtr-slc-001 named[15896]: zone trizon.com/IN/external: sending notifies (serial 42)
```

Comment: IPs still the same?

Comment: yeah the ip should all be the same

Answer (score 0):

Use nslookup to verify bind is running. If it's running see if it can answer about the web addresses.

Most likely bind is not running, restart bind then check `/var/log/syslog`, `/var/log/kern.log` and `/var/log/daemon.log` if they exist. You can use the following to restrict output to only the last 50 lines:

```
tail -50 /var/log/syslog
```

Restarting will cause bind errors to be the last entries in the logs so you can see what's going on.

Comment: i took a look at all those logs and I don't see anything wrong.